# Selecionar mais de um item em select ou algo parecido angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, html-select

Necessito de selecionar mais de uma opção em meu select ou algo parecido com ele, existe esta possibilidade?

```
<select ng-model="modelcompraevenda.filial" class="form-control" >
      <option  ng-selected="data.unit == 1"  ng-selected="true" 
               ng-repeat="x in modelcompraevenda.listFiliais" 
               value="{{x.idFilial}}">{{x.nomeFilial}}>
      </option>
</select>
```

Comment: O HTML tem `multiple` nativo. Um atributo do `<select>`. Já testaste isso?

Comment: não conheço, vou pesquisar sobre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gabriel,

Como o **@Sergio** disse, você pode utilizar o componente `multiple` no seu `select`.

```js
(function(angular) {
  angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {}]);
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js">
</script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <select ng-model="selecionados" multiple>
      <option value="1">Valor 1</option>
      <option value="2">Valor 2</option>
      <option value="3">Valor 3</option>
    </select>
    <p>MultiSelect Selecionados = {{selecionados}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

você pode substituir os `Option` pelo seu `ng-repeat` normalmente.

Aproveite e leia mais sobre o [Select no AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)

Comment: Jackson tomei a liberdade de colocar o seu exemplo no sua resposta, angular, jquery, javascript com interações com HTML funciona e fica uma resposta ao meu ver bem completa ... !!! Se não pode reverter !!!

Comment: Obrigado @VirgilioNovic, escrevi tão pouco código que nem pensei nisso :) .